# Yearly income and expenses table

Tags: mysql, database

i have two tables 
**Income** 
(id, 
income,
date,
userid) 
and table
**Expense**
`(id,amount,date,userid)`. Now I'm trying to create a View with sum of income, sum of amount in one year. Also it must be `GROUPED by year` and `userid`.

So new table (view) must have sum of income, expenses, year. Right now i am stuck on this code.

```
SELECT
    id,
    i.Prihod,
    e.Rashod,
    YEAR
    YEAR(COALESCE(e.god, i.godi))) AS Godina , 
    users_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            sum(insum) as 'Prihod',
            YEAR(datum) as 'Godi',
            users_id 
        FROM
        GROUP BY users_id
    ) as i
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        sum(amount) as 'Rashod',
        YEAR(datum) as 'God',
        users_id
    FROM expense
    GROUP BY users_id

) as e
```

Comment: AFAIK MySQL doesn't permit derived tables (subqueries in from clause) in a view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the *structured* part of *structured query language.* Start with three subqueries (virtual tables).

First:  A list of the years and users. You need this because MySQL doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN` capability. If you write this query correctly, it will contain one row for each user for each year you need.

```
              SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datum) Godi, users_id FROM income
              UNION
              SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datum) Godi, users_id FROM expense
```

Second, a summary of the income by year and user.

```
               SELECT sum(insum) as Prihod,
                      YEAR(datum) as Godi,
                      users_id 
                 FROM income
                GROUP BY YEAR(datum), users_id
```

Third, a similar sum of expenses by year and user

```
               SELECT sum(amount) as Rashod,
                      YEAR(datum) as God,
                      users_id 
                 FROM expense
                GROUP BY YEAR(datum), users_id
```

Next, test these subqueries individually, standalone, to ensure you have the results you expect.

Finally, join them together as if they were tables, like so

```
SELECT yr.users_id, yr.Godi, inc.Prihod, exp.Rashod
  FROM (
              SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datum) Godi, users_id FROM income
              UNION
              SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datum) Godi, users_id FROM expense
       ) yr
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT sum(insum) as Prihod,
                      YEAR(datum) as Godi,
                      users_id 
                 FROM income
                GROUP BY YEAR(datum), users_id
       ) inc ON yr.users_id = inc.users_id AND yr.Godi = inc.Godi 
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT sum(amount) as Rashod,
                      YEAR(datum) as God,
                      users_id 
                 FROM expense
                GROUP BY YEAR(datum), users_id
       ) exp ON yr.users_id = exp.users_id AND yr.Godi = exp.God
```

The query pattern here is to develop three subqueries. The first of them determines the number of rows in your final result set, because it contains one row for each desired row.  The second and third queries have one, or maybe zero, rows for each row you need in your final result set.  Then you join them together.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to debug this; also I don't know your native language so I may have misunderstood your column names. If so, sorry.

Comment: i used your query and it works just fine, but where to put a WHERE ( i need to insert - WHERE users_id=".$id." - ) $id is ($id = $_SESSION['user_session'];)